# Wordpress Plugin Fails on activation

Tags: wordpress

I been working in a WP plugin. Since I was working in my local host I installed the plugin on early development and then started add features. When I tried to compress the completed plugin and install it on a live site I get an Error:

> The plugin generated 12624 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

And all admin page gets outputted on the site:

[image]

Seems like this only happens on install via Wordpress. If I copy the files via FTP this does not happen. I suspect the problem in on the admin page that I have some echoes, since I was able to get an error pointing to the line. But like I say it only happens on the activation, if otherwise the plugin works just fine. The error pointed to this line:

```
<div class="wpcm-pull-left wpcm-section-title"><?php echo(isset($_GET['wpcm_edit_bubble']) && isset($wpcm_edit_item) ? 'Editing Existing Preview' : 'New Item Preview'); ?></div>
```

I have an inline if to echo something. Not sure what to do. I tried doing this:

```
function wpcm_admin()
{
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'wp_bubble_menu') {
        include('admin_edit.php');
    }
}
```

Only include the admin code if page is 'wp_bubble_menu' but even that seems to be ignore, the admin code gets outputted all over. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a silly mistake. I had the plugin file header in the admin file. It is only supposed to go on the main file of the plugin.